# $h:B\to B'$ is a homomorphism, then $h(x\lor y) = h(x) \lor h(y)$

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

*I was able to complete the proof, but I'm afraid I may have used a circular argument or made too many assumptions somewhere. A better/simpler proof would be nice.*

> Consider two boolean algebras $(B,\leq, \lor, \land,^c,0,1)$ and $(B',\leq, \lor, \land,^c,0,1)$. A map $h:B\to B'$ is a homomorphism, if for all $x,y\in B$ we have:
>
> - $h(x\land y) = h(x) \land h(y)$
> - $h(x^c) = (h(x))^c$
>
> Then show that $h(x\lor y) = h(x) \lor h(y)$ for all $x,y \in B$, $h(0) = 0$ and $h(1) = 1$.

*My work:*

I started with $h(x\land y) = h(x) \land h(y)$ and got $(h(x\land y))^c = (h(x) \land h(y))^c$. Then, using De-morgan's laws (**is it okay to use these**?) and $h(x^c) = (h(x))^c$, I ended up with $h(x^c\lor y^c) = h(x^c) \lor h(y^c)$. Now, we know that a Boolean algebra is a **complemented** lattice, i.e. every element $x \in B$ has a complement $x^c \in B$. So $h(x^c\lor y^c) = h(x^c) \lor h(y^c)$ essentially means $h(p\lor q) = h(p) \lor h(q)$ for all $p,q \in B$, which proves what is desired. Is this last line of reasoning okay?

Lastly, putting $y = x^c$ in $h(x\land y) = h(x) \land h(y)$ and $h(x\lor y) = h(x) \lor h(y)$ gives $h(0) = 0$ and $h(1) = 1$.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use DeMorgan: We can easily compute
\begin{align*}
 (x^c ∨ y^c) ∧ (x ∧ y) &≤ (x^c ∧ x) ∨ (y^c ∧ y) = 0 \\
 (x^c ∨ y^c) ∨ (x ∧ y) &≥ (x^c ∨ x) ∧ (y^c ∨ y) = 1,
\end{align*}
so in fact equality holds, meaning $x^c ∨ y^c = (x∧y)^c$, as complements are uniquely characterised by the complement axioms. Your proof works out.

Comment: The line of reasoning about which you express some doubt can be tidied up simply by putting $\ x=v^c\ $ and $\ y=w^c\ $ in your established identity $\ h\big(x^c\vee y^c\big)=h\big(x^c\big)\vee h\big(y^c\big)\ $ to get $\ h(v\vee w)=h(v)\vee h(w)\ $ for any $\ v,w\in B\ $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems fine. Double negation makes your life easier when combined with De Morgan: $$h(x\vee y) = h(x^{cc}\vee y^{cc}) = h((x^c \wedge y^c)^c) \stackrel{(\ast)}{=} (h(x)^c\wedge h(y)^c)^c = h(x)\vee h(y),$$where in $(\ast)$ we used the two homomorphism axioms in one shot.

Then for $0$, you have $$h(0) = h(x \wedge x^c) = h(x)\wedge h(x)^c = 0,$$and for $1$ we have $$h(1)= h(x \vee x^c) = h(x)\vee h(x)^c = 1.$$